# Write NSDictionary to Cache and also remove it

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to write NSDictionary object to cache and also want to remove it from cache. here i store it to chache but can not remove it from chache

```
    -(void) storeDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *) dictionaryToStore strDictionaryName:(NSString *) strDictionaryName
{
//get the documents directory:
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cacheDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//make a file name to write the data to using the
//cache directory:
NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", cacheDirectory,strDictionaryName];

if (dictionaryToStore != nil) {
    [dictionaryToStore writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:YES];
}
}
```

Help for remove it from cache.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some rough code for deleting a file in cache folder, suppose you have  the file path named `fullFileName` as showed in your code.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL fileExist = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullFileName];

if (fileExist) {
    NSError *error;
    BOOL ok = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:fullFileName error:&error];
    NSLog(@"remove %d",ok);
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error is %@", error.description);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to write it to the cache. **NSCache** might be the best and the most convenient way to do that.

Here is the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/index.html

However, if you want to have the full manipulation. You probably stick with what you are doing. You just delete the whole when you want to delete it and override it when you want to update it. Because **NSCache** will be handled by system. When system does not have enough memory, it might clear your data so that you have to check it every time you want to access it. It really depends on what you want.

Comment: NSCache is transient, the question seems to be around persisting the Dictionnary

Comment: It's not that transient. The system will clear that as long as the system does not have enough memory.